# PHP File upload to server using a url

Tags: php, file-upload, box

Client would like to be able to upload a pdf file to his websites server by pasting in a url from his box app. eg   https://app.box.com/s/f5xy8uimm9g07x1l5z1m

The form has the following text field in it:

The form directs to a php script

```
if(isset($_POST['urlf']))
      {
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); 
$file_url = $_POST['urlf'];
  $save_to = "../flyers/";
  $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
   file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
 $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $content;
      }
else
{
//script to input $ad_link to sql db and/or save file if uploaded locally - this part works
}
```

as the script is now, no file is uploaded (the directory is chmode writable) and the value of $ad_link is null in sql

is what I'm trying to do impossible? or is there an error in my code, if so what is error?

Comment: You haven't specified a file name. `$save_to` is a directory.

Comment: You do know `$content` is the content of the file you are downloading and saving? You should create a filename, since `$save_to` is having a directory and not a filename.

Comment: I would like to keep the name of the file, do you have a reccommendation how to do this?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois how do i extract the file name?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois explode(".", what variable do i place here);

Comment: `$urlbits = explode("/", $_POST['urlf']); $last = count($urlbits) - 1; $filename = $urlbits[$last];`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois that saves the filename as the word Array

Comment: @CharlotteDunois wait i'm an idiot hold on testing